# Is it mandatory to eat before solar noon on Rosh Chodesh?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, eating, rosh-chodesh-new-month, chatzos

"A person should make sure to eat before the sixth hour on Shabbos, since it is forbidden to fast on Shabbos". --A [column](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5764/yisro/otravis.htm) by Daniel Yaakov Travis, citing Talmud Yerushalmi, Taanis 3:11.

During Chanukah, too, it's [generally forbidden](http://www.shamash.org/lists/scj-faq/HTML/faq/05-15.html) to fast. Yet a ChabadTalk forum poster [writes](http://www.chabadtalk.com/forum/showthread.php3?p=162494#post99352) that, during Chanukah, there's no requirement to eat before solar noon.

On Rosh Chodesh, as well, it's generally forbidden to fast. See, for example, [this chapter](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/05-01-06/) of Peninei Halachah.

Is Rosh Chodesh like Shabbos in that it's mandatory to eat before solar noon?

Comment: There is a distinction between shabbos, which has a REQUIREMENT of Se'udah, and Rosh Chodesh, where acts of mourning (and therefore fasting) are prohibited. Tanis cholom is a good contrast: fasting on Rosh Chodesh is fine, but doing it on shabbos requires taking an ADDITIONAL fast during the week to make up for fasting on shabbos and being mevatel the mitzvas hayom.

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Eliezer Melamed](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/05-01-06/), quoting [Biur Halacha 418 Rosh Chodesh Asur](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40448&st=&pgnum=174) & [Kaf Hachaim 418:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9085&st=&pgnum=339), says it is forbidden for one to not eat in order to fast. However, if it happens that one does not eat for a while there is no problem. Thus the answer is that it is not mandatory to eat before solar noon, so long they are not intentionally fasting.

> ולכן אסור להתענות בו (שו"ע תיח, א). וכל הנמנע מלאכול אפילו שעה אחת
>   לשם תענית, עובר באיסור, אבל אם באקראי לא הזדמן לו לאכול כמה שעות, אין
>   בזה חשש איסור - באו"ה תיח ד"ה 'ר"ח אסור'; כה"ח ג

Rabbi Dov Lior was asked whether or not one may eat prior to Musaf on Rosh Chodesh. He [responded](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?id=37203) that it is permitted, unlike on Shabbos where it is required to eat a Seuda before solar noon.

Comment: The source doesn't mention noon at all...

Comment: @DoubleAA: Correct. Even way past noon.

Comment: No. You have no evidence of that at all? He would say it's forbidden to purposefully fast from 2-5 pm, even if you ate before noon.

Comment: Chiyuv Seudah is not at all the same as not fasting! Drinking water for instance obviates the latter without fulfilling the former.